# Material - pass directive to child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I use the Stapler material, and I need to pass a custom directive to the component, to access the properties of the element by app directive.
I tried to write:

```
  <mat-vertical-stepper labelPosition="bottom">
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps" [label]="step" customDirective></mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

But the resulat HTML is:

```
<div class="mat-step-text-label ng-star-inserted">Step</div>
```

Without my directive.

How can I do it?

[Exemple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9huhk-mynogd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom.directive.ts)

Comment: Can you provide code of your directive and the module it's included into? Better reproduce the app on stackblitz

Comment: I removed my answer, but you can use https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9huhk?file=src/app/custom.directive.ts example.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? Please have a look at the example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9huhk-4xwcmx?file=src/app/custom.directive.ts